# Expanding hover area to outside element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, jquery-events

I have a dropdown menu, which the sub-menu placed on different element. So basically when the mouse leave the menu item, the sub-menu get closed immediately because the sub-menu is not the child.

```js
var menuItem = $(".menu-item");


menuItem.hover(hoverIn, hoverOut);

function hoverIn() {
  var mnItemMeta = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect();

  $(".sub-menu").css({
    opacity: 1,
    left: mnItemMeta.left
  })
}

function hoverOut() {
  $(".sub-menu").css({
    opacity: 0
  })
}
```

```css
html,body{background-color: #efefef;}
.menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
.sub-menu {
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .2s ease;
}
.sub-menu-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu Item</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="sub-menu">
  <ul class="sub-menu-list">
    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yans_fied/6wj0of90/

The question is how to extend the hover area, so when the cursor point into sub-menu it ignore the `hoverOut` action.

NOTE: don't tell me to place the sub-menu inside the menu-item, I already how that worked. It's for different case that need the sub-menu to be placed outside the menu-item.

Comment: you can use `jquery` for that,

Comment: You need to make the element which is being hovered larger, or put the sub-menu inside it

Comment: If your sub menu needs to be out side, then, when user points to the submenu link, then how can you open the sub menu. Hence the sub-menu needs to be inside the main menu it self.

Comment: @Samir have you checked my snippet? so basically it like tab ui which hold tab id to open the tabcontent.

Comment: I got your problem, There is a solution for your question. Simply increase the bottom padding of the `li` having class `menu-item`. Make sure the `sub-menu` and the li should attached to each other. But the problem is, if user wants to click on the sub menu, at this time the user has to come out of the parent `li`, and hence the `sub-menu` will hide automatically. How much you will increase your parent `li` bottom paddnig? Can you?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Okay, i have figured the solution. Thanks to all  of you for giving some advice, but I can't accept the answers from you guys since the solution need more workaround.

So, basically a i created two function, which is `startCloseTimeout()` and `stopCloseTimout()`, and bind it on both `menu-item` and `submenu`.

Here is the function itself:

```
var startCloseTimeout = function (){
    closeDropdownTimeout = setTimeout( () => closeDropdown() , 50 );
},

stopCloseTimeout   = function () {
    clearTimeout( closeDropdownTimeout );
};
```

And here is how i bind to mouse events:

```
//- Binding mouse event to each menu items
menuItems.forEach( el => {

    //- mouse enter event
    el.addEventListener( 'mouseenter', function() {
        stopCloseTimeout();
        openDropdown( this );
    }, false );

    //- mouse leave event
    el.addEventListener( 'mouseleave', () => startCloseTimeout(), false);

} );

//- Binding mouse event to each sub menus
menuSubs.forEach( el => {

    el.addEventListener( 'mouseenter', () => stopCloseTimeout(), false );
    el.addEventListener( 'mouseleave', () => startCloseTimeout(), false );

} );
```

### So, how this code work?

By creating close timeout handler we can control when the dropdown should close or not.

When the mouse is entering the menu-item this is what happen:
1. Stop current running `closeDropdownTimout`
2. Open related dropdown menu

when the mouse is leaving the menu-item it start the `closeDropdownTimout`.

But how the dropdown menu still open? Since we set the same action on dropdown menu, the `closeDropdownTimout` well be cleared and canceling the close action.

For full source code you can check it out on codepen http://codepen.io/ariona/pen/pENkXW

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You could just place the `sub-menu` in the `menu-item`.

```js
var menuItem = $(".menu-item");
menuItem.hover(hoverIn, hoverOut);

function hoverIn() {
  var mnItemMeta = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect();

  $(".sub-menu").css({
    opacity: 1,
    left: mnItemMeta.left
  })
}

function hoverOut() {
  $(".sub-menu").css({
    opacity: 0
  })
}
```

```css
html, body {
  background-color: #efefef;
}
.menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
.sub-menu {
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .2s ease;
}
.sub-menu-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu Item</a>
    <div class="sub-menu">
      <ul class="sub-menu-list">
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Another way would be to check the `hover` state of `.menu-item` and `.sub-menu`. You need to work with a little timeout here, to prevent it from closing to early.

```js
var timeout,
    hovered = false,
    menuItem = $(".menu-item, .sub-menu").hover(hoverIn, hoverOut);;

function hoverIn() {
    hovered = true;

    var mnItemMeta = this.getBoundingClientRect();

    $(".sub-menu").show().css({
        opacity: 1,
        left: mnItemMeta.left,
    });
}

function hoverOut() {
  hovered = false;

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        if (!hovered) {
            $(".sub-menu").css({
                opacity: 0,
            }).hide()
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

```css
html, body {
  background-color: #efefef;
}
.menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
.sub-menu {
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .2s ease;
}
.sub-menu-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="sub-menu">
  <ul class="sub-menu-list">
    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @eisnehr i already know that, but this is for different layout, the the sub-menu need to be placed outside the menu-item. :)

Comment: I've extended my answer with a second example @ArionaRian

Comment: Hi @eisnehr, can you check this for me? https://jsfiddle.net/yans_fied/6wj0of90/ It's seem it need more workaround

Answer (score 3):

You could add

```
.sub-menu::before{
     content:'';
     height: <height of menu item>
     width: 100%;
     position:absolute;
     bottom:100%;
}
```

and place the `hoverOut` on the `.sub-menu`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example where

1. a pseudo element is added to the submenu to provide an overlapping area for the hover. It is yellow only for demo purposes.
2. the hover out of both the menu and the submenu only set a variable. The submenu is hidden in a separate function, wich evaluates the variables. A slight timeout is needed to allow for the change from one to the other.

```js
var menuItem = $(".menu-item");
var submenuItem = $(".sub-menu");

var hoverMenu = false;
var hoverSubmenu = false;


menuItem.hover(hoverIn, hoverOut);

function hoverIn() {
  hoverMenu = true;
  var mnItemMeta = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect();

  $(".sub-menu").css({
    opacity: 1,
    left: mnItemMeta.left
  })
}

function hoverOut() {
  hoverMenu = false;
  setTimeout (hide, 10);
}

submenuItem.hover(hoverSmIn, hoverSmOut);

function hoverSmIn() {
  hoverSubmenu = true;
}

function hoverSmOut() {
  hoverSubmenu = false;
  setTimeout (hide, 10);
}

function hide() {
  if (hoverMenu == false && hoverSubmenu == false) {
    $(".sub-menu").css({
      opacity: 0
    })
  }
}
```

```css
html,body{background-color: #efefef;}
.menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
.sub-menu {
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .2s ease;
}
.sub-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 100%;
  height: 26px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.sub-menu-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu Item</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="sub-menu">
  <ul class="sub-menu-list">
    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I played a while on your script today, starting with your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yans_fied/6wj0of90/), not the partial snippet...

You were so close...
But the thing is that you have two different parent element classes to handle (read: event handlers to bind to them)... And to handle differently.

When you move the mouse from an element that opened the sub-menu to another that should keep it opened, some events should not trigger. A `mouseout` event should occur only if the mouse do not enter another `menu___item` or a `dropdown-menu__content` "fast enought".

`mouseenter` and `mouseout` are quite **fast** on the trigger... Faster than human mouse move.

## A small 100ms delay is usefull here.

A `setTimeout()` to set `dropdown-holder` to `display:none` on leaving these elements and a `clearTimeout` on entering.

```
$(".menu__item").hover(
  function() {
    $(".dropdown-holder").css({"display":"block"});
    displaySubMenu( $(this) );
    clearTimeout(NavDelay);
  },
  function(){
    setNavDelay();
  });

$(".dropdown-menu__content").hover(
  function() {
    clearTimeout(NavDelay);
  },
  function(){
    setNavDelay();
  });
```

The setTimout function is simple:

```
function setNavDelay(){
  NavDelay = setTimeout(function(){
        $(".dropdown-holder").css({"display":"none"});
    },100);
}
```

And here is the sub-menu display function, which was not modified that much:

```
function displaySubMenu(element){
  var itemMeta = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  //console.log( itemMeta );
  var subID = element.data('sub');
  console.log(subID);

  var subCnt = $(subID).find(".dropdown-menu__content").css({"display":"block"});
  var subMeta = subCnt[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  //console.log( subMeta );
  var subCntBtm = subCnt.find(".bottom-section");

  menuHoveredID = subID;  // Let's Keep this info in memory in a var that has global scope

  $(drBg).css({
    "display":"block",
    "left": itemMeta.left - ((subMeta.width / 2) - itemMeta.width / 2),
    "width": subMeta.width,
    "height": subMeta.height
  });
  $(drBgBtm).css({
    "top": subCntBtm.position().top
  });
  $(drArr).css({
    "display":"block",
    "left": itemMeta.left + itemMeta.width / 2 - 10
  });
  $(drCnt).css({
    "display":"block",
    "left": itemMeta.left - ((subMeta.width / 2) - itemMeta.width / 2),
    "width": subMeta.width,
    "height": subMeta.height
  });

  // Ensure the right content is displayed
  $(".dropdown-menu__content").css({
    "display":"none"
  });
  $(menuHoveredID).find(".dropdown-menu__content").css({
    "display":"block"
  });
}
```

To ensure the right content is displayed, the `menuHoveredID` variable is brougth to the function via the `mouseenter` handler of `menu__item` `hover`.

Your onload declarations:

```
var dr = $(".dropdown__content"),
    drBg = $(".dropdown__bg"),
    drBgBtm = $(".dropdown__bg-bottom"),
    drArr = $(".dropdown__arrow"),
    drMenu = $(".dropdown-menu__content"),
    drCnt = $(".dropdown__content"),

    menuHoveredID ="",
    NavDelay;
```

I Stripped off the unnessary and added two vars...
If you notice, I also corrected semicolon / coma... ;)

**[Working CodePen here](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/ALqzmg?editors=0011)**

Comment: Thanks for this elaborate answer, but i've figured it out before you posted it :D, the setTimeout really do the job for this case.

Comment: Good. Another thing I forgot to mention, I used `display:none` instead of `opacity:0` because the links from the sub-menus are still cliquable even when not visible (In Chrome, maybe not all browser)... You will see the hand pointer if you look for it. ;)

Comment: that can be fixed with `pointer-events: none` or switching z-index :)

Answer (score 1):

if you change your first js line to: `var menuItem = $(".menu-item, .sub-menu");` and then add `top: 3em;` to the `.menu-list` css (to provide a tiny overlap with the `.menu` div and remove the flicker)then all should be good.

```js
var menuItem = $(".menu-item, .sub-menu");


menuItem.hover(hoverIn, hoverOut);

function hoverIn() {
  var mnItemMeta = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect();

  $(".sub-menu").css({
    opacity: 1,
    left: mnItemMeta.left
  })
}

function hoverOut() {
  $(".sub-menu").css({
    opacity: 0
  })
}
```

```css
html,body{background-color: #efefef;}
.menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
.sub-menu {
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .2s ease;
  top: 3em;
}
.sub-menu-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu Item</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="sub-menu">
  <ul class="sub-menu-list">
    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @ArionaRian, had a quick go at the new fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/manoeuvres/73452ken/ the menu triggering is unreliable due to in part to the way the triangle relates but there may be some of the other tweaks you wish to retain for the next iteration.